# Jagged list not printing / Selenium WebElement not updating?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, multidimensional-array

All.

The following section of code below is a snippet from a larger program, using Python 3.x. The `colorSkusArray` has values:

`[[https://us.testcompany.com/eng-us/products/test-productv#443],[https://us.testcompany.com/eng-us/products/test-productv#544],[https://us.testcompany.com/eng-us/products/test-productv#387]]`

```
    listTwo = []
    for a in range(0, len(colorSkusArray)):
        browser.get(colorSkusArray[a])
        print(colorSkusArray[a])   # the link to each skus page we'll pull views from
        sBin = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("// *[ @ id = 'lightSlider'] / li / img")
        listOne = []
        for b in sBin:
            storer = b.get_attribute('src')
            print(storer) # the src of each img on the sku's page
            listOne.append(storer)
        print('NEXT ELEMENT')
        listTwo.append(listOne)
        del sBin
        del storer
        del listOne[:]
    print(listTwo)
```

The printout from this reads:

```
https://us.testcompany.com/eng-us/products/test-productv#443
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM2_Front%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Side%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Interior%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Other%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Other%20view2.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
NEXT ELEMENT
https://us.testcompany.com/eng-us/products/test-productv#544
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM2_Front%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Side%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Interior%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Other%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Other%20view2.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
NEXT ELEMENT
https://us.testcompany.com/eng-us/products/test-product#M543
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM2_Front%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Side%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Interior%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Other%20view.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
https://us.testcompany.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/test-productv#443_PM1_Other%20view2.jpg?wid=140&hei=140
NEXT ELEMENT
[[], [], []]
```

The issue I'm having appears(?) to be with the `sBin` WebElement. What is supposed to happen:

1. The link of each page visited gets printed: SUCCESS. See the
   address before each of the 5 following addresses from `storer`.
2. The link to each view (5) for each product gets printed:
   UNSUCCESSFUL. See the same 5 links to the same 5 views are printed,
   three times over. Each of these three blocks should have 5 unique links, but apparently the same 5 links are being referenced three times over.
3. The full list of lists (`listTwo`) should be printing with all its contents: UNSUCCESSFUL. See the three empty lists in `listTwo`'s printout at the bottom of the output.

Regarding 2): I've been looking at this for close to four hours now, and cannot figure out what's going on. All I can guess after debugging for a while is that the `sBin` variable may not be updating properly. I inserted a `del` command to reset it at the end of each loop, but this didn't resolve the issue. Otherwise, I don't know why the same 5 `src`'s keep getting appended, despite a new link being passed into the browser.get() method each time.

Regarding 3): I have printed lists of lists before, so I believe PyCharm should be able to handle this printout. Perhaps those I've printed in the past were different in some way (accounting for the difference in output here), but as far as I am aware, they were exactly the same. I've read about using Numpy for printing arrays, but as far as I can tell, it isn't *necessary* to print here.

I am new to Python and Selenium, so all suggestions and comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved 2. By placing `browser.quit()` at the end of the `for` loop, the `sBin` WebElement is now updating properly with each iteration of the loop. I understand why this works, although I don't understand why it is necessary. It doesn't answer my original question, but it does apparently resolve the issue...

Regarding 3., I still don't know what's wrong. If a list (e.g. `List[0]`) will print out its contents just fine, I don't understand why a jagged list just prints empty `[]`.